# PDFBOX - if multiple files are attached to pdf, last file that gets attached is not opening

Tags: java, pdfbox

when we have around 10 files to attach to pdf, the 10th file that gets attached is not opening. It is displayed properly in attachments, but it wont open. File is not corrupted.
pdfbox version : 2.0.16
PFB code:

```
---------------Caller method code ---------------------------      
    // add the new node as kid to the root node
    List<PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode> kids = new 
    ArrayList<PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode>();
    int i=0;
    for(String fileName : inboundFileNamesList)
    {
        i++;
        attachFileToReport(pDDocument, kids, fileName, i);
    }
    efTree.setKids(kids);
    // add the tree to the document catalog
    names.setEmbeddedFiles(efTree);
    pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setNames(names);
```

--------------caller method code ends-------------------------------------

```
    private void attachFileToReport(PDDocument pDDocument, 
    List<PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode> kids, String fileName, int fileIndex) 
    throws IOException
     {
       try
        {
        LOGGER.info("Picked GCAS file -> " + fileName);

        PDComplexFileSpecification fs = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
        fs.setFileUnicode(fileName);

        File file = new File(fileName);

        // now lets some of the optional parameters
        PDEmbeddedFile ef = new PDEmbeddedFile(pDDocument, new FileInputStream(file));
        ef.setSize((int)file.length());
        LOGGER.debug("file size attached-> " + ef.getSize());
        ef.setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        fs.setEmbeddedFile(ef);
        LOGGER.debug("Embeded file -> " + fs.getFile());

        LOGGER.debug("fileIndex -> " + fileIndex);

        // create a new tree node and add the embedded file
        PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode treeNode = new PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode();
        treeNode.setNames(Collections.singletonMap("File Index"+ fileIndex, fs));

        kids.add(treeNode);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Exception while attaching file : " + fileName + " to report");
    }

}
```

Comment: @535646, can you please help here

Comment: Current pdfbox version is 2.0.21. What number is the limit? Does it happen with 2?

Comment: @535646, it is randomly happening. it mostly works with 2 files. Seems happening if we have more files  .For some reason some of the files in attachments are not opening  . Not sure if any input/output streams are causing any issues

Comment: Another important thing: always use `setFile()` **and** `setFileUnicode()`, also `setEmbeddedFile()` **and** `setEmbeddedFileUnicode()`. Also call `setSize()` and `setSubType()` (see EmbeddedFiles.java example from the current source code download). Please share a file that shows the problem and one that doesn't.

Comment: @535646, do you i should do both the following:  fs.setEmbeddedFile(ef); fs.setEmbeddedFileUnicode(ef); ?  Also, its not issue with file that is getting attached. the same file gets attached properly if i keep less number of files. as of now i see issue with 10 files getting attached and last file to attach is not opening. it is showing proper file size. So not sure if size limit is causing issue or any streams. I dont see option in comment to attach file, Please let me know how i can attach the file.

Comment: the files getting attached are cumulatively reaching around 3mb. is there any file restrictions? can we do anything with filesizes?

Comment: I don't know about size restrictions. Upload your files to a sharehoster and post the links.

Comment: The problem with the tenth entry ***may*** be that it is not attached in order. "File Index1" through "File Index9" are added to `kids` in their correct order but "File Index10" would have to be between "File Index1" and "File Index2" (lexical order). I say "may" because the specification only requires that the **Names** arrays are sorted but doesn't require any specific order in the **Kids** arrays. But probably this is just another missing detail in the specification...

Comment: i changed File Index1,2,3 to use randon UUID or just use file names. but still no luck

Comment: @535646, you are right . i gave index as just alphabets a,b,c etc . it worked. Is it possible to fix specification? i think it as long as they are unique they should work.